# UIView added on top of window does not rotate on iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation, uitabbar, uiwindow

I have a `tabBar` based application and want to present some custom view above whole screen (not as modal view) and I do it like that:

```
[self.view.window addSubview:self.myViewController.view];
```

The reason I did this is because this way view is positioned above `UITabBar`.

Anyway view is presented nicely and it covers whole screen like I want to. But there is a problem. When I rotate device this top view does not rotate, but view's underneath do.

I've tested on `iOS5` and `iOS6` without luck. Have also put this code in delegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Similar code is in myViewController's view:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

The view just doesn't rotate... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know only the first subview of the window gets the rotation events. You're adding another view (your view) to the window and therefore need to deal with propagating the rotation events yourself.

Providing some really quick-help for you, just check out the following implementation : [AGWindowView](https://github.com/hfossli/AGWindowView) (not maintained from 2016)

Comment: Ok, I'll have to do another way. Probably better solution to replace rootViewController. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, what you can do is add it as a subview of the first window subview (i.e. as a subview of your rootViewController's view). 'UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!window) 
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:myView];'

Comment: I've just tried this and it works. But on rotation change UITabBar shows up and that disappears again...

Comment: Not "only the first subview". Only one, yes. Only the upper-most visible subview and it's parent view(or viewController's view) on the responder chain can rotate.

Comment: please add right link for your demo. below link is doesn't exist .so please add link .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the rootController for your UIWindow.
e.g:

```
fileprivate(set) var bottonOverlayWindow = UIWindow()

self.bottonOverlayWindow.rootViewController = self;
```

// 'self' will the ViewController on which you had added UIWindow view. So whenever you ViewController change the orientation, your window view also change it's orientation.

Let me know if you face any issue.